# Is building the Linux kernel on a case-insensitive filesystem possible?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, compiling, case-sensitivity

Linux kernel source has some overlapping filenames which would collapse when put on a case insensitive filesystem. Here is the list as of 6.4.7:

- in `include/uapi/linux/netfilter/`:

  - `xt_CONNMARK.h` and `xt_connmark.h`
  - `xt_DSCP.h` and `xt_dscp.h`
  - `xt_MARK.h` and `xt_mark.h`
  - `xt_RATEEST.h` and `xt_rateest.h`
  - `xt_TCPMSS.h` and `xt_tcpmss.h`
- in `include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/`:

  - `ipt_ECN.h` and `ipt_ecn.h`
  - `ipt_TTL.h` and `ipt_ttl.h`
- in `include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv6/`:

  - `ip6t_HL.h` and `ip6t_hl.h`
- in `net/netfilter/`:

  - `xt_DSCP.c` and `xt_dscp.c`
  - `xt_HL.c` and `xt_hl.c`
  - `xt_RATEEST.c` and `xt_rateest.c`
  - `xt_TCPMSS.c` and `xt_tcpmss.c`
- in `tools/memory-model/litmus-tests/`:

  - `Z6.0+pooncelock+poonceLock+pombonce.litmus` and `Z6.0+pooncelock+pooncelock+pombonce.litmus`

After the source tree is populated in a case-insensitive filesystem, one file from each of these pairs will overwrite the other. Obviously, it would not be possible to build the Linux kernel with netfilter enabled. Even if both versions of the files are saved under different names and the source modified to acknowledge these renames, the API would be broken, and who wants that?

Would it be possible to build the Linux kernel without netfilter support? What other challenges might arise in the process?

Comment: "_if both versions of the files are saved under different names and the source modified to acknowledge these renames, the API would be broken_" - really?

Comment: @roaima Yes, the API would be broken, because instead of including `xt_CONNMARK.h`, I would need to include `xt_connmark_uppercase.h`, and so on. I doubt this can be fixed with some preprocessor magic.

Comment: Anyway, think longer term. Suppose you got it all working. Will you maintain your Linux "case insensitive compilation" fork? Because for sure this will never go upstream.

Comment: I have no plans on creating such a fork, I am only asking what the possible challenges are. I have now tried building on ext4 with casefold option, NTFS and FAT32 so far.